# Can i change the event that triggers when Kendo Grid next page button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with pageable true. I want to trigger a custom function with Next page in kendo grid paging  is getting clicked?

Comment: a workaround could be find the class over next button, and bind function to it on onload() or $().ready(function{ //bind event here });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to trigger a callback in the change event of the datasource bound to the grid.

> Fired when the data source is populated from a JavaScript array or a
>   remote service, a data item is inserted, updated or removed, the data
>   items are **paged**, sorted, filtered or grouped.

[Datasource Change Event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-change)

**JS CODE**

**Subscribe to change on initialisation**

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products",
      dataType: "jsonp" //"jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
    }
  },
  change: function(e) {
    // PLACE YOUR CALLBACK CODE HERE
  }
});
dataSource.fetch();
```

**Subscribe to change post initialisation**

```
function callback(e) {
  // PLACE CALLBACK CODE HERE
}
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products",
      dataType: "jsonp" //"jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
    }
  }
});
dataSource.bind("change", callback);
dataSource.fetch();
```

Comment: Yes it works. However i wanted custom jquery events for them as i am implementing grid custom pagination.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what to do:
Set pageable attribute with your custom object as below, and add your own change function:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "productName" },
    { field: "category" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
    { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
    { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
    { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
  ],
  pageable: {
    pageSize: 2,
    change:function(e){
         console.log("grid pager clicked!");
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked however now i am using custom pagination now. So no inbuilt paging for kendo.

Comment: Incredible that this event is not documented in the kendo grid official doc for pageable!!! In fact, I suppose that, in the "pageable" property of the kendo grid, we can set any property available in the external "pager" widget?  
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/pager

Answer (score 0):

The solution dcodesmith gave your will work but as an alternative you could bind to the click event on the page links, the following jQuery selector should work:

```
$(".k-link.k-pager-nav")
```

And you can get the page it will go to using the page data attribute.

Comment: That should work too but I wanted to keep things kendo-fied and follow the API and documentation provided by them. ;)

Comment: I used your way because it did not wanted change events for grouping, filtering and sorting. I just wanted pagination event because i am implement a custom pagination for grid.
Thank you:)